# How can I split a string into an array and determine WHICH character came after the split?

Tags: regex, arrays, actionscript-3, split

I'm trying to split all the words in a string into an array in AS3. The obvious answer of course would be to simply do this:

```
str.split(/\s/);
```

The problem here is that I need to be able to tell whether the split occurred on a newline or a space. I'm trying to put the words of a string into draggable boxes, and I want the ones after a newline to go, well, on a new line.

Any idea the best way to go about this? Clearly, the above split method will get rid of the crucial newline character that will tell me what I need to know.  Should I use a regex.exec with a while loop, or is there any way to use split to preserve the characters I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example string :

```
     This is an example string  
     with spaces as well as newlines 
     and needs a regex
```

1/ Split the string on newline, get array#1.

> array#1 =  [ "This is an example string","with spaces as well as
>   newlines","and needs a regex" ]

2/ For each element in array#1 , split based on your current regex which will break the strings
   only on spaces as newlines have already been dealth with, this 2-D array is array#2

> ```
>    array#2  = [ 
>                 ["This","is","an","example","string"] ,
>                 ["with","spaces","as","well","as","newlines"],
>                 ["and","needs","a","regex"]
>               ]
> ```

3/ Process elements of array#2 as you want.

Comment: *Bangs head against desk* I should have thought of this myself. This works even better than trying to capture the newline character. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First split you string at the newline

```
var lines:Array = str.split("\n");
```

Now you can loop on you lines and split each of these in to seperate words

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    var words = str[i].split(" ");
    for(var j:int = 0; j < words.length; j++){
        trace("word", words[i]);
    }
    trace("newline");
}
```

Comment: Actually, this works even better than the solution I was thinking of. I should have thought of it myself. Thanks!